# Wess-Zumino-Witten vs. Yang-Mills-Chern-Simons and Kac-Moody$.$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

There is a really nice (holographic) duality between 2d Wess-Zumino-Witten and 3d Yang-Mills-Chern-Simons models (cf. Ref.1). For example, for a given gauge group $G$, the spectrum of both theories is given by the integrable representations  (of the affine extension) thereof.

From an algebraic point of view, the underlying structure that governs WZW is the Kac-Moody algebra satisfied by its currents. This is precisely how the integrable representations arise.

On the other hand, CS models are also based on the integrable representations of the gauge group, but in this case I see no trace of a Kac-Moody algebra. The main article on CS theories (Ref.2) does not mention this algebra anywhere, and neither does the rest of references I've consulted.

Because the duality above is very well-established, I do expect to find a KM algebra somewhere within CS, but I'm having troubles to work out the details. Where exactly is the algebra? Which objects satisfy it?

**References.**

1. nLab - [*Holographic Principle*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/holographic+principle#OrdinaryCSWZWModel), (Ordinary Chern-Simons theory / WZW-model).
2. nLab - [*Chern-Simons theory*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons+theory).

Comment: And the award for the most names in a title goes to...